# Show the previous content for 5 seconds even if the state updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

I have a React application which uses a Django backend, I have used webSocket to connect with the backend which updates state when there are some changes. But the changes are very rapid, so only the last changes are visible. I want to show the previous message for a certain time before next message is displayed. Here is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const Text = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const webSocket = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    webSocket.current = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/some_url/");
    webSocket.current.onmessage = (res) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(res.data);
      setMessage(data.message);
    };
    return () => webSocket.current.close();
  }, []);

  return <p>{message}</p>;
};

export default Text;
```

So the message should be visible for certain time (in seconds, for eg - 5 seconds), then the next message should be shown. Any idea how that could be done?

Comment: Do you want the slow down to be using debouncing, throttling, or queueing?

Comment: Which ever is the most simple

Comment: They're semantically different, and you should be considering which one makes the most sense for the data you're displaying from the websocket.

Comment: I'm a beginner so I don't know about these terms very much, I was looking for a simple solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Text = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const currentMessage = messages[0] || "";

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

  // webSocket ref missing? ;-)

  useEffect(() => {
    webSocket.current = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/some_url/");
    webSocket.current.onmessage = (res) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(res.data);
      setMessages((prevState) => [ ...prevState, data.message]);
    };
    return () => webSocket.current.close();
  }, []);

  // Remove the current message in 5 seconds.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer || !messages.length) return;

    setTimer(setTimeout(() => {
      setMessages((prevState) => prevState.slice(1));
      setTimer(null);
    }, 5000));
  }, [messages, timer]);

  return <p>{currentMessage}</p>;
};
```

Comment: WOW, such a smart solution. This works perfectly for me. I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: As a note here: if the messages keep coming faster than you remove them, the `messages` array will blow up in size. This can be OK if you're debugging for a limited time. Otherwise you'll also want to set a size limit and a way to discard messages.

Comment: No that will not be the case, I have some issue with the above code. If I keep receiving messages from the backend, the currentMessage only changes when we stop receiving the messages. I want to change the currentMessage while I'm getting messages. How can we achieve that?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for that. I'll edit the answer: the timeout should be reset only when popping messages, not queueing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom hook to handle the message transition. Pass as argument the desired time you want to wait before showing the next message. You can use it in other parts of your code:

**useQueu.js**

```
const useQueu = time => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(null); //--> current message
  const queu = useRef([]); //--> messages

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setCurrent(queu.current.shift());
    }, time);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [current]);

  const add = obj => {
    if (!current) setCurrent(obj); //--> don't wait - render immediately
    else {
      queu.current.push(obj);
    }
  };
  return [current, add];
};
```

**Text.js**

```
const Text = () => {
  const [message, add] = useQue(5000);
  const webSocket = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    webSocket.current = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/some_url/");
    webSocket.current.onmessage = (res) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(res.data);
      add(data.message); //--> add new message
    };
    return () => webSocket.current.close();
  }, []);

  return <p>{message}</p>;
};
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dmu5wl?file=src%2FApp.js)